# Setting up Nektar impact LX25+ in Ubuntu

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, jack, midi

I'm running Ubuntu on a Dell XPS 13 with Waveform free primarily as my DAW. I just bought a shiny new controller keyboard and I can't get a blip out of it. I initially tried setting it up with my shiny new soundcard (SSL2+) both connected via USB but again no sound. So I simplified my approach and tried to just get it to communicate with fluidsynth/qsynth and then vmpk. Also no joy.

So far I have tried the following:

- I followed these instructions first (https://nektartech.com/using-waveform-tracktion-with-impact/), no problems there but no signal or sound in waveform or any of the other software.
- Then I tried everything here (http://tedfelix.com/linux/linux-midi.html), Yes everything. Again, nothing worked, no visible input on the meters when I press a key and no sound.
- using lsusb in terminal I can see the device is connected.
- aconnect -i and aconnect -o both also show connections so I figure it can send MIDI messages back and forth, from what I've read, is that right to assume?

I'm not so technically savvy with these things but I'd love to get something working. I've spent 4 days now trying various things on the web. Any help, advice much appreciated.

Comment: Please be specific with details, what do you consider the *latest*?  Ubuntu 20.10 or the 2020-October release?  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (second latest, but latest LTS release), today's *daily* (in which case which one...) etc...   It's best if we're told what you're running instead of guessing, the latest to you means what?

Comment: Oh yeah sure. Its LTS 20.04.2. Is there any significant difference between the latest and second latest that affects audio processing, MIDI integration or any other such functionality?

Comment: edit made. Seeing as you're so freely giving out advice, I';; assume you wouldn't mind hearing a bit too. Whilst your point might be correct in that I don't have the 'latest' version, I firstly can't imagine that there's so much difference in the April to October update that it affects the answer to the main body of my question, to which so far, you've offered absolutely no helpful advice. 

So please, next time, if you don't want to discourage new people in this community when you comment on a question why not offer something constructive alongside the pedantry.

Comment: There are large differences, six months of software stack makes for a fair amount of change... don't forget Linux is the largest & fastest moving project in the world (according to Microsoft..) and your question is rather close to kernel where the change is largest between versions, unlike user geared software (eg. firefox, libreoffice etc where difference is negligible in significance), so release does matter on devices, and software dealing with the hardware (& thus kernel stack).

Comment: I never said it didn't matter, I said the difference in regards to actually answering my question is most likely nominal but clearly you're more concerned with flashing your feathers as you've demonstrated once again. In the future please read the comments properly before responding.

Comment: @TomEdwards did you get the controller working and if so, what was your solution?

Comment: I did but I can't remember exactly how. I think a combination of the guides I cited in the original post helped somewhat just not perfectly. Hope it helps.